# How to retrieve an attribute using getElementsByTagNameNS in php?

Tags: php, xml

I want to pull the news feed from "http://rapfix.mtv.com/feed" for a website that I'm creating. I have everything working other than, being able to pull the URL location of the image for each article.

In this feed, the image URL is showing up like this in the code:

```
<media:content url="http://rapfix.mtv.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/tyler-handcuff.jpg" type="image/jpeg" height="300" width="575">
<media:text type="plain"><![CDATA[tyler-handcuff]]></media:text>
</media:content>
```

I've read from another stackoverflow question, that you're able to pull information from the node using something like this:

```
$item_pic = $article->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/', 'content')->item(0);
```

But now, I'm trying to get the "URL" attribute out of it. Here's a look of my code:

```
$xml=("http://rapfix.mtv.com/feed");

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

$x = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

foreach($x as $article){
        $item_title = $article->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $item_link = $article->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $item_desc = $article->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $item_pic = $article->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/', 'content')->item(0);

        echo ("<strong><a href='".$item_link."' target='_blank'>".$item_title."</a></strong><br />");
    echo ("<div><div class='FloatLeft'><img src='".$item_pic."' width='100' height='100'/></div><div class='FloatLeft'>".$item_desc." - <a href='".$item_link."' target='_blank'>Read More</a></div>^");
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace for your target element is media. The element name is content. The Namespace URL for the media namespace is http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/. Thus:

```
foreach($x as $article)
{
        $nlContent = $article->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'content');
        if( $nlContent->length > 0 )
                $item_pic = $nlContent->item(0)->getAttribute('url');
        else
                $item_pic = '/images/noimageavailable.jpg';
        echo $item_pic . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, I got mixed up with which one I'm supposed to use for the Namespace. Now I went ahead and made the necessary changes but I'm getting this **Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string** I assume I can't just echo $item_pic.

Comment: Nope, you need to get the node's url attribute. Editing.

Comment: That's what I originally tried once I fixed the Namespace. I used: `$item_pic = $article->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'content')->item(0)->getAttribute('url');` But then I get this error **Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object**

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. Not every article has one.

Comment: Oh ok, so the getAttribute() does work just if one article does not have an image then it throws off the entire script? In that case, I'll try to put an "IF" condition on $item_pic, maybe something like this `if($item_pic = $article->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'content')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')){
   $image = '<div class="FloatLeft"><img src="'.$item_pic.'" width="100" height="100"/></div>';
  }else{
   $image = '';
  }`

Comment: GOT IT!!! `if($item_pic = $article->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'content')->item(0)){
$image = '<div class="FloatLeft"><img src="'.$item_pic->getAttribute('url').'" width="100" height="100"/></div>';
}else{
$image = '';
}` Hopefully this helps someone else out there. Thanks Mel :)

Comment: @SoRec Edited my example. Tested it locally and perfectly dumps all image urls when available and the stub image when not.